# How much HTTP_REFERER helpfull for Rest api security?

Tags: php, rest, security

how many `HTTP_REFERER` is important for tracking of api hit..

I have two resource

1. android app
2. website

how much this will help to secure our apis in both places?

Comment: If you want security use OAuth2.

Answer (score 3):

not at all if security is your concern as HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing
Your best strategy in to use encoding based on a secret key known only to the client and server to have both end encryption